# Serialize only simple types using Json.Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am not sure why anybody has not asked about this question yet but I am trying to serialize only simple types of a given object using `IContractResolver` interface. I don't really want to mark each property using `ShouldSerialize` method or `JsonDataAttribute` or anything like this.

What I have done so far shown as following on LinqPad

**Some sample classes to serialize**

```
class Customer
{
    public List<Order> Orders {get;set;}
    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public string[] Addresses {get;set;}
}

class Order
{
    public int OrderId{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Amount {get;set;}
    public Order PreviousOrder {get;set;}
}
```

**An extension method to serialize all the objects**

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string JsonSerialize (this object obj)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.ContractResolver = new MyContractResolver();
        settings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
        settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj,settings);
    }
}
```

**My Custom Contract Resolver Class**

```
public class MyContractResolver: DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member,memberSerialization);
        property.ShouldSerialize = instance => instance.GetType().IsPrimitive || instance.GetType() == typeof(string) || instance.GetType() == typeof(decimal);
        return property;
    }
}
```

**and Main method:**

```
void Main()
{
    var customer = new Customer
                {
                    Orders = ProduceSomeOrders(),
                    Addresses = new string[] {"9450 S. Small Street Dr.","9521 Flintstone Dr. S"},
                    CustomerId = 1
                };

    var jsonOrder = customer.JsonSerialize();
    jsonOrder.Dump();
}
```

I only want to serialize sample types such as `int`,`double`,`string`,`decimal`,`bool` etc. but not arrays, collections, custom objects etc. and it will only navigate the first level, not 2nd or more levels down. I really wonder why there is not any simple method which does this in Json.Net.

This is the output when I run this code: (an empty json)

> { }

I've realized one thing when I run this code, the first `member` parameter passed into the `CreateProperty` method is the main object itself which in this case is `Customer` instance.  But since this will work for all sort of types I just don't want to say `instance.GetType() == typeof(Customer)` or something like this in the method. The expected output in this case is only `CustomerId` in this case.

Do you know any graceful way to handle my problem?

Comment: What is the expected outcome of the serialization? Based on what I read it should contain only CustomerID, is that correct?

Comment: @Patrick : You're right!

Comment: In the JsonSerialize method, is it possible to iterate the properties of the "top instance", in order to serialize its child properties, and then somehow mash them together into a valid json string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By changing the method below I got the result: {"CustomerId":1}.  Is this what you were looking for?

```
public class MyContractResolver:DefaultContractResolver
{
protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    var property = base.CreateProperty(member,memberSerialization);

    var propertyType = property.PropertyType;
    if(propertyType == typeof(int) 
        || propertyType == typeof(string)){
        property.ShouldSerialize = instance => true;
    }
    else
    {
        property.ShouldSerialize = instance => false;
    }
    return property;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of overriding `CreateProperty` method, I am overriding `GetSerializableObjects` method as it gives all the possible members I will get:

```
public class MyContractResolver: DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        var members = base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType);
        var filteredMembers = new List<MemberInfo>();
        members.ForEach(m=>{
            if(m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
            {
                PropertyInfo info = (PropertyInfo) m;
                var type = info.PropertyType;
                if(type.IsPrimitive || type == typeof(string) || type == typeof(decimal))
                {
                    filteredMembers.Add(m);
                }
            }
        });
        return filteredMembers;
    }
}
```