# Serialize object just root level with NEWTONSOFT

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-3.1

I have classes like this:

```
public abstract class EntityBase 
{
    
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreationTimeUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? ModificationTimeUtc { get; set; }

}

public class State : EntityBase 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City : EntityBase 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public long StateId { get; set; }
}
```

so, I create a state variable

```
var state = new State()
        {
            Name = "State 1",
            CreationTimeUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            Id = Sequence.Generator.Next(),
            Cities = new List<City>()
            {
                new City()
                {
                    Id = Sequence.Generator.Next(),
                    CreationTimeUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                    Name = "City 1"
                }
            }
        };
```

When I serialize state variable with `NewTonSoft`, it returns a string like this:

```
{"name":"State 1","cities":[{"name":"City 1","stateId":"265439108547260417","id":"265439108547260419","creationTimeUtc":1638876015097,"modificationTimeUtc":1638876015097}],"id":"265439108547260417","creationTimeUtc":1638876015097,"modificationTimeUtc":1638876015097}
```

I wanna to create just root object, In this case I need to ignore `Cities` property.
I can't use `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on `Cities` property.
I want to use `JsonSerializerSettings` or somethings like that to generate json string.

Update

I use this code to generate json string

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { 
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        };
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(state, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

How can i do that!?
thanks

Comment: Why can't you use `JsonIgnore`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Because just in this case I want to ignore this property, not always

Comment: I can  not see  CreationTimeUtc  and   Id  in your  State class.  Your code can not be compiled. Pls post the real code that can be compiled at least.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010583/newtonsoft-json-way-of-ignoring-properties-without-adding-jsonignore

Comment: You could use a custom contract resolver as shown in [Serialize only simple types using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15929848/3744182).  Does that answer your question?  If not could you [edit] your question to clarify what additional help you need?

Answer (score 0):

Json is just a format to move data between servers. It uselles alone. To use it you need to deserialize it. just  use it

```
var cities=state.Cities ;
state.Cities=null;

var json= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(state,Formatting.Indented,
      new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

state.Cities=cities;
```

it was tested in Visual Studio. This is json

```
{
  "name": "State 1",
  "id": "265439108547260417",
  "creationTimeUtc": 1638876015097,
  "modificationTimeUtc": 1638876015097
}
```